# Java, two objects, object1 = object2 = class/type ... don't understand

Tags: java, class, object, instance

I have two instance variables, head and tail. In the code there's a line:

```
head = tail = new Node<E>();
```

Does this mean that there are two instances, head and tail, of class Node? I'm quite confused here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It simply means:

```
tail = new Node<E>();
head = tail;
```

So there are 2 references (`head` and `tail`) pointing to the same `Node<E>` instance.

Comment: No offense meant, but this answer is not that good . . . the question shows a lack of understanding of what an "instance" and a "reference" are.  This answer doesn't, imho, speak to that.

Comment: Might want to mention that the reason this works is because assignment statements in java have return values. IE: `tail = new Node<E>()` will assign the new object to the variable "tail" and also return a reference to that new object, which can be used as part of another assignment.

Comment: Thank you, ivanovic, for your answer has cleared my confusion and I now understand instance references.

Answer (score 4):

This means there are TWO references to ONE Object `Node`.

The line `tail = new Node<E>();` actually returns a value (in this case an object reference) equal to the assigned value.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's only one *instance* of `Node<E>`created, but both `head` and `tail` refer to it, so you have two reference variables that point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Only one instance of `Node`. Both `head` and `tail` references pointing to same instance.

Answer (score 2):

No certainly not.

Here's what's happening in this code, in sequence.

1. 'new' is used to create an instance, aka an object, of the Node class
2. a reference to this instance is stored in the tail reference
3. a reference to this instance is stored in the head reference.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 references `head` and `tail` are both assigned to the *same* single instance of `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

Only one object is created, head and tail both references the same object.

Answer (score 0):

```
object1=object2 ;
```

Here  Object1 one refrence to other means simply object2 is copied all addresses to object1 reference

Simply object2 is copied into object1